# Find the derivative of $-8t/\sqrt[3]{ t^2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find the derivative of $-8t/\sqrt[3]{t^2}$

How do you get the answer $\dfrac{-8t^{-2}}3$ ?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{t}{\sqrt[3]{t^2}}=t^{1/3}$

Comment: Did you forget the denominator in the exponent? The answer should be $-\frac{8}{3}t^{-\frac{2}{3}}$.

Comment: The title is different from the body of question.

Comment: Anna- Sorry thats what I meant to  post as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Assuming there is no typo:*

We have $\sqrt [3]{t^2} = t^{\frac {2}{3}} $. Thus we get $$f (t) = \frac {-8t}{t^{\frac {2}{3}}} = -8t^{1-\frac {2}{3}} = -8t^{\frac {1}{3}} $$ Thus the derivative comes out to be $$\boxed {-8\frac {1}{3}t^{\frac {1}{3}-1} = -\frac {8}{3} t^{-\frac {2}{3}}} $$ Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks I don't know why I thought I was done when I got to  -8t^1/3